# Perl script to configure grep output

Tags: perl, bash, grep

I have a pipe-delimited log file with the following column format:

```
<date>  <time> | <fruit> | <color> | <num_1> | <num_2> | <num_3>
```

So for example:

```
2013-03-27  23:01:52 | apple | green | 55 | 120 | 29
2013-03-27  23:01:56 | plumb | purple | 28 | 1 | 394
2013-03-27  23:01:59 | apple | red | 553 | 21 | 7822
```

I would like to write a perl script (though python or bash is acceptable as well) that `greps` out the `<date>` and `<time>` field (column 1) and either `<num_1>`, `<num_2>` or `<num_3>`, depending on the input you give the script. Hence running `perl extract.pl 2` on the above information would give you `<date>`, `<time>` and `<num_2>`:

```
2013-03-27  23:01:52 | 120
2013-03-27  23:01:56 | 1
2013-03-27  23:01:59 | 21
```

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $col = $1;

print `grep "myapplog.txt" "m/_(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)/ | $col"`
```

Here, I'm setting the `col` var to the script's first arg, and then trying to print the grep matching the datetime of the first column and the desires `<num_X>` column. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$1` is not the first argument to your script. That would be `$ARGV[0]`. `$1` is the contents of the first regex capture buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using perl in awk-mode

```
$ perl -F'\|' -lane 'print $F[0]," | ", $F[4]' input
2013-03-27  23:01:52  |  120 
2013-03-27  23:01:56  |  1 
2013-03-27  23:01:59  |  21
```

Pure awk:

```
awk -F"|" '{print $1, "|", $5}' input
```

Pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS="|"

while read -a ARRAY;
do
    echo ${ARRAY[0]} "|" ${ARRAY[4]}
done < input
```

**update**

The pass e.g. a parameter to the awk-solution to determine witch column to print, use:

```
$ awk -vcol="5" -F"|" '{print $1, "|", $col}' input
```

in bash, the first parameter to function/script resides in `$1` so use that as an index into ARRAY.

Something more official than a one-liner, using python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

col = raw_input('which column to print? -> ')
try:
    col = int(col)
except ValueError:
    print >> sys.stderr, "That was no integer"

with open("input") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        tmp = line.strip().split('|')
        print tmp[0], "|", tmp[col]
```

Comment: Thanks @Fredrik Pihl (+1) - I'd be interested in the perl-awk combo but should have mentioned that my log files are huge and don't contain just those 3 lines of log entries. So it looks like the rules out your first suggestion (perl-awk). For the other 2, I have no preference, but don't know how I'd invoke them from the command line and what to give them as inputs. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

using the first argument like in your wish (use `@ARGV` array, not `$1` in `perl`):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings; use strict;
use autodie; # No need to check open() errors

$\ = "\n";   # output record separator (no need \n)

# file-handle
open my $fh, "<", "myapplog.txt";

chomp(my $col = $ARGV[0]);

die("Not an integer !\n") unless $col =~ /^\d+$/;

# using the famous and magical <diamond> operator:
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my @F = split /\|/; # splitting current line in @F array
    print join("|", @F[0,$col+2]); # join on a array slice
}

close $fh;
```